# Checking for Datatype on each element of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So i have column named "ID" which have the format ["AB12345M","CD34567G",IJ87654P"]. So it has 2 letters,5 number and a letter in the end. Now i have to write a function that goes thru each row of this column and check on this format to make sure i am getting 2 letters in the beginning 5 numbers followed by a letter in the end.

I have written a this function to access each element but i am not sure where i am wrong.

```py
def data_types(df):      
if type(df.iloc[1]) == str or type(df.iloc[1]) == object: 
print("okay")      
elif type(df.iloc[2]) == str or type(df.iloc[2]) == object: 
print("okay")      
elif type(df.iloc[3]) == int: 
print("okay")      
elif type(df.iloc[4]) == int: 
print("okay")      
elif type(df.iloc[5]) == int: 
print("okay")     
elif type(df.iloc[6]) == int` 
print("okay")     
elif type(df.iloc[7]) == int: 
print("okay")      
elif type(df.iloc[8]) == str or type(df.iloc[8]) == object: 
print("okay")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

we can use `.str.contains`

firstly, don't use loops in pandas, it's an anti pattern.

we can try the following regex `[A-Za-z]{2}\d{5}\w{1}$`

> - [A-Za-z]  matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
> - {2} matches the previous token exactly 2 times
> - \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
> - {5} matches the previous token exactly 5 times
> - \w matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
> - {1} matches the previous token exactly one time (meaningless quantifier)
> - $ asserts position at the end of a line

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col' : ["AB12345M","CD34567G","IJ87654P", "failme"]})

df['check'] = df['Col'].str.contains('[A-Za-z]{2}\d{5}\w{1}$',regex=True)


print(df)

        Col  check
0  AB12345M   True
1  CD34567G   True
2  IJ87654P   True
3    failme  False
```